# Safari/Firefox or Chrome wont to use http/2 yet CURL is fine

Tags: apache, firefox, safari, openssl, nghttp2

I repeated the following using SLES and OS X. I compiled apache 2.4.18, nghttp2-1.8.0 and OpenSSL 1.0.2g and using a recently built version of curl it appears everything is working fine.

```
  curl https://macbookpro.xxxx/ --cacert /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl/server.crt --verbose
```

Output from the above shows the connection upgrading to http/2 and the Apache access logs report:

```
  192.168.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2016:15:12:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2" 200 45
```

The certificate chain is all locally generated. With a root, intermediary and server certificates and the  following commands report everything is OK

```
openssl s_client -connect macbookpro:443 -CAfile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl/server.crt
```

However I just cant get any of my browsers Safari/Firefox or Chrome to utilise http/2.

- Firefox 45.01 (with spdy indicator extension)
- Safari 6.2.8 (8537.85.17.9.1)
- Google Chrome 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)

The page displays fine, but firefox's spdy indicator extension shows nothing. The access logs all report HTTP/1.1 connections. How do I get http2 working?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: cURL uses IETF issuing policies, while browsers use CA/B issuing policies. For the differences, see [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27931596/608639) and [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639)

Comment: Are you using any anti-virus software? http://serverfault.com/questions/752767/trying-to-setup-http2-on-apache

Comment: Nope, no anti-virus software. I tried chrome, firefox and safari from two different macs running different OS. No virus checkers on either.